# Django rest framework timefield input format

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, timefield

After hours of searching, I found many posts that are related but wasn't able to help.

What I want to do is input eg: 10:30 AM into the TimeField.
 
In the django rest framework API on the browser, it is using this 10:30 AM format (`'%I:%M %p'`). 
But when I am using postman to test it, the output is in 24hr format ('%H:%M:%S'). I also tried to use 10:30 PM as input but the output I get is 10:30:00 instead of 22:30:00.

Many of the answers I found suggest to change the TimeField format in `settings.py` by using this line:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p',)
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Sorry for my inexperience on django rest framework as I am still learning.

Here is the screenshot of the result.
On browser API:

[image: On browser API]

On postman:

[image: On postman]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the documentation on the [TimeField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#timefield) you will see:

> Signature: `TimeField(format=api_settings.TIME_FORMAT, input_formats=None)`

Where

> `format` - A string representing the output format. If not specified, this defaults to the same value as the `TIME_FORMAT` settings key, which will be `'iso-8601'` unless set. Setting to a format string indicates that to_representation return values should be coerced to string output. Format strings are described below. Setting this value to None indicates that Python.
>
> `input_formats` - A list of strings representing the input formats which may be used to parse the date. If not specified, the `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` setting will be used, which defaults to `['iso-8601']`.

So you either can specify the `format` and `input_formats` on the serializer, or set the `settings.TIME_FORMAT` and `settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS`.

Let's set the first case:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    birthTime=serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats='%I:%M %p')
```

---

Some suggestions:

1. Make your variable names snake case: `birth_time`.
2. You may need to play a bit around with the input format because you may expect many different inputs:

   ```
   input_formats=['%I:%M %p','%H:%M',...]
   ```

Comment: I tried using this in serializer.py            

        `class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            birthTime = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_format='%I:%M %p')

            class Meta:
                model = MyUser
               fields = ('userId', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'birthday', 'birthTime', 'ethnicGroup', 'mobileNo', 'favoriteClinic',)`
but i got this error instead:
` __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_format'`
Sorry for the line spacing, shift+enter doesnt work .

Comment: @JinNiiSama That was my fault, the correct argument is `input_formats` (I edited the answer as well)

Comment: Alright, the error is gone but i have another problem, 
https://imgur.com/a/AA8d2
Im pretty sure this is the correct format but i end up getting error for the format. Now im getting confuse with the format. Sorry for these small trouble

Comment: I solve the problem with this:    

`valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']`    

Then in the input_formats=valid_time_formats.    
Now it work properly

Comment: @JinNiiSama good to know, If my answer helped you, you can accept it :)

Comment: this works for me: **time_day_start = serializers.TimeField(format="%I:%M %p", input_formats=["%I:%M %p", "iso-8601"])**, otherwise you wil have validation errors on write

Answer (score -1):

Convert the result in Serializer validate method and return it.

```
import time
t = time.strptime(timevalue_24hour, "%H:%M")
timevalue_12hour = time.strftime( "%I:%M %p", t )
```